# NGRX Effects - Where/How to organize effect definitions.

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm using @ngrx/effects in an angular2 application, and struggling with the organization of the different effect definitions.

I have to entities, `Identity` and `Subscription`, each with their own Actions services `IdentityActions`, `SubscriptionActions`, as well as their effects services `IdentityEffects`, `SubscriptionEffects`.

The following actions are defined.

```
IdentityActions.AuthorizeIdentity()
IdentityActions.OnIdentityAuthorized(identity)
SubscriptionActions.GetSubscriptionList(identity)
SubscriptionACtions.OnSubscriptionsListed(subscriptions)
```

After an identity is authorized, I immediately want to get a list of it's subscriptions.  How does `@ngrx/effects` advocate the organization of these effects so that it is traceable/easy-to-find later (e.g. a year from now)?

In IdentityEffects:

```
@Effect()
this._actions.ofType(authActions.AUTHORIZE_IDENTITY))
  .switchMap(() => this.svc.AsyncAuth())
  .switchMap((identity) => authActions.OnIdentityAuthorized(identity))

@Effect()
this._actions.ofType(authActions.ON_IDENTITY_AUTHORIZED)
  .switchMap((identity) => Observable.of(action, subActions.GetSubscriptionList(identty))
```

This seems natural when writing it, because getting the subscription list is an effect of an identity getting authorized... but I'm concerned because if a developer is ever trying to track down where the subscription list is getting fetched from, it isn't intuitive to go digging around in the IdentityService.

The alternative is to register a 2nd effect in CustomerEffects that doesn't emit..

```
@Effect({emit: false})
this._actoions.ofType(authActions.ON_IDENTITY_AUTHORIZED)
  .switchMap((identity) => Observable.of(action, subActions.GetSubscriptionList(identity))
```

This seems like it would be easier to find in the long run... But feels less natural when writing it (I'm writing an identity side effect in the subscriptions service...)

What is the time-tested approach (if there even exists enough time)?

Comment: Have you looked at their [example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app)?

Comment: It's not clear what some of those snippets do. For example, what is `action` in the last snippet? The action that triggered the effect? If so, why re-emit it? It would already have been passed to the reducers. And if `GetSubscriptionList` updates some state using some mechanism other than a dispatched action, what you are doing is no longer Redux.

Comment: I was under the impression my service names were pretty standard. 

subActions is a class that exposes methods that emit actions related to subscriptions to the store.  It also contains constants for action type resolution.   The last effect dispatches two actions, the one it intercepted (so that the identity gets applied to state) and a second one which emits a "GetSubscriptionList" action. 

The question, i think anyway, is pretty clear.  What is the best practice for registering an effect that is outside the primary resource scope of a file.

Comment: I have looked at the sample app.. it is so simple that none of their concerns even have a potential to cross a boundary like this. 

When someone log's in, a side effect is getting a list of their subcriptions.  I can't find any clear guidance on where it is recomended this side effect be registered... as an IdentityEffect or a SubscriptioEffect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a ton of great feedback here but I want to follow up with the direction I went.

I decided that it makes the most sense to group effects by the entity that is effected, rather than by what causes the effect.

95% of the time, this results in an effects service definition that pertains to exactly one entity... in some instances however there may be one or two effects that reference something else.

In my example, an Identity is authenticated, and that causes subscriptions to get loaded.

*IdentityEffectsService.ts*

```
@Effect()
public AuthorizeIdentity$ = this._actions.ofType(AUTHORIZE_IDENTITY)
  .switchMap(() => this._identitySvc.Authorize())
  .map(identity => this._identityActions.OnIdentityAuthorized(identity))

@Effect()
Public OnIdentityAuthorized$ = this._actions.ofType(ON_IDENTITY_AUTHORIZED)
  .do(identity => console.log(`${identity.name}` logged in!`));
```

*SubscriptionActionsService.ts*

```
@Effect() ListSubscriptions$ = this._actions.ofType(LIST_SUBSCRIPTIONS)
  .map(action => <Identity>action.payload)
  .switchMap(identity=> this._subscriptionSvc.List(identity))
  .map((subs) => this._subscriptionActions.OnSubscriptionsListed(subs))

@Effect() OnSubscriptionsListed$ = this._actions.ofType(ON_SUBSCRIPTIONS_LISTED)
  .do(action => console.log(`${action.payload.length} subscriptions listed.`)

/ * This was the effect in question.
    I've grouped it with the other subscription effects because I believe it
    will be more natural for someone trying to understand how subscriptions
    get filled to find it here in the future. 
*/
@Effect() OnIdentityAuthorized$ = this._actions.ofType(ON_IDENTITY_AUTHORIZED)
  .switchMap(identity => this._subscriptionActions.ListSubscriptions(identity))
```

Obviously, would still love to have someone with more experience with the @Effects pattern on medium/large projects chime in.